# Using similar 1 android apps for many apps with different name and different settings

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to use 1 android apps with different name and different settings? I trying to make 1 hotel booking application that is used by several hotels, so this application can be published by the hotel self on Google Play Store with different names without re-developing application

Comment: sure, noone cares.

Comment: Yea, you can do it. Read about white labeling app, example article here: https://proandroiddev.com/android-flavours-white-labeling-an-app-46a17b8b27a4